# Animating text on iOS

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I'm writing an iOS app which needs to generate and animate individual text characters dynamically. The actual text being displayed will be dynamic and I want to use layers and masks to animate individual characters. Does anyone have any experience of what is the best and/or easiest way to do this? I've been looking at CoreGraphics and CATextLayer.

Is CATextLayer actually just making CG calls under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only way to do this is with CAAnimation. You'll have to animate each character individually.

I don't think that CALayer is making calls to CG-stuff, because it's a pretty full calss on it's own and doesn't need other frameworks. The only CG-stuff that is using is CGFont.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do this is by calling drawRect (via setNeedsDisplay) off of a timer (or CADisplayLink).  Just update the xy location (rotation, size, etc.) of each character each animation frame and redraw the view containing the characters.